# auto form fill in ms access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have a small question regarding the auto fill ms access forms.

I have a table with different orders from the customers and i have done a table structure which will take all the input data from the front end form.

The problem is that the user have to enter all the data several times like most of my form fields are same and just some fields has to change for the next record.

i just need to know like how can i auto populate fields by entering a article number i have to get all the records and so that i can edit what ever i need to change and i can save the new record.

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you mean but.
What I think you want to do (and correct me if i'm wrong) is to populate certain fields of new record in a form based on the article number? 
If so The thing i can think of is to do it in VB code and do something like

```
Me!fieldname.SetFocus
Me!fieldname.Text = "the value here"
```

If there are a lot of different articlenumbers you can use a sql query to perhaps select the field values from  a previously inputted record with that articlenumber? I don't know if that the best and easiest way to do it, I'm pretty new to access myself.

Comment: I tried the vb code before but there is one problem like i tried to fill the form just one field which is acting as a base for retriving the data is taking primary key in its value iam trying to figure out the problem thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do that, you're going to want an unbound form.  Have a textbox (call it txtSearch for now) and a button (call that btnSearch).  Then, behind the scenes, when you press the Search button you can query the dataset for the record you want to start with.  Something like this:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE FieldToSearch = '" & Me!txtSearch & "'")

'Now pull back the data from the recordset, one field at a time, and drop it in the form
Me.Field1.Text = rec("Field1")
Me.Field2.Text = rec("Field2")
'etc...
```

This will allow you to fill in each field on your form with the appropriate field from the table.  Then, after the data is entered, have a separate button that will write the data to the table.

Comment: Just for information I want a combo box where i will enter the article number and it has to give the related fields regarding the article and so i can use them the fields to edit and create a new record with the same article number.

Comment: Just for example google online autofill forms where i will enter only my name and it will fill all the details regarding me in the form as the data regarding me is stored and used a autoform fill option I just want to know whether it is possible with ms access or not

Comment: Yes it is, and I described how to do it above.